# How to run multiple python files concurrently when accessing the login screen

Tags: python, php, python-3.x

```
<h1>LoginPage</h1>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<div>
    <label>
        NUMBER：
        <input type="text" name="id" required>
    </label>
</div>
<div>
    <label>
        PASSWORD：
        <input type="password" name="pass" required>
    </label>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Login">
</form>
```

I would like to write a code that would make the separate self-made ultiface_ac.py and myface_ac.py run concurrently when the above login screen is accessed.

The php exec function, for example, did not give me the result I wanted because it would execute the python file first and return the result before accessing the login screen. I would like to run the python file at the same time as accessing the login screen, but no matter how much research I do, I can't figure it out. Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: There isn't enough information here to answer your question. Does "at the same time as accessing the login screen" mean when the form action login.php is executed?

Comment: What's the  use case for this? What do the python scripts do? Do they need to have finished executing before the user then submits the form?

Answer (score 1):

PHP pages work by receiving inputs via get/post and answering with html. The flow of the data is very much a one way road and once you have printed your code, your process is done.

You CAN use `proc_open()` and `fork()` to run processes in parallel, but they need to be orchestrated by a background process otherwise they'll be killed by the end of the PHP page execution (aka. as soon as the login page is served to the client).

One thing you can do is to have the login page save a flag on server side that another process running periodically, as a cron job for example, can read and run your background stuff for you.

Another option would be having a JS calling a php page in the background that hangs until the processes are done while the user is doing a login.

There's no clean way of doing it in PHP, unless you're coding a whole webserver using it.